# In the FullCalendar, How can I add an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm doing work attendance management function, an employee of the month attendance to read from the database to the FullCalendar. I need, in the absence of attendance records to date, to add a click event, identifying the content for being late or other.

Now I don't know how to add data to the events in, first.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: now I'm read data form database to show in the FullCalendar, the datas is  the attendance of One employee in One month.May be some day is empty, At this time，i want to click the day,and add an event in it to identify,may be late,may be no sign

Comment: Why not answer your own question then?

Comment: I have answered.(*^__^*) 嘻嘻……

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fullcalendar add events dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920314/fullcalendar-add-events-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

```
var event={title: 'New Event', start:  selectDate};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a form/modal to add data in calendar and add

```
dayClick: function(start, end, allDay) {     
 alert();
}
```

or you can use

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
 alert();
}
```