# How to add default events for all dates except particular dates in full calendar

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using full calender.js in my application. I tried to put default 
   events fro all dates except particular dates which are coming from db 
  those are different events rather than default and each date cell 
  contains only one event .I failed to put default event for all dates I 
  tried so many times  but i failed to achieve it. Please help me how to do 
  this?

This is my code

```
  <div id='calendar'></div>

   <script>
    $(function() {

     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       eventClick: function(eventObj) {
        if (eventObj.url) {
           alert(
           'Clicked ' + eventObj.title + '.\n' +
           'Will open ' + eventObj.url + ' in a new tab'
          );

          window.open(eventObj.url);

           return false; // prevents browser from following link in 
  current tab.
      } else {
    alert('Clicked ' + eventObj.title);
  }
},
defaultDate: '2018-10-15',
events: [
  {
    title: 'simple event',
    start: '2018-10-02'
  },
  {
    title: 'event with URL',
    start: '2018-10-03'
   }
   ]
  });

  });
 </script>
 <style>
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}

  #calendar {
max-width: 900px;
margin: 40px auto;
}
  </style>
```

Comment: i want to put defauult event for all dates except  28-11-2018, 29-11-2018 dates i didnt get plz help me

Comment: What you have tried?  Do you have some error in your browser console?

Comment: no i didnt get any error

Comment: iam trying to  put defalut event like 1500 amount for all dates which are going to be edit except some dates which are coming from db like 28-11-2018 and 29-11-2018 these are with different amount should show in calender

Comment: iam showing different amount for two dates 28 and 29 but iam not able to show default amount for all dates

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920314/fullcalendar-add-events-dynamically/29306198](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920314/fullcalendar-add-events-dynamically/29306198)

Comment: how to put default events for all dates except some array of dates?